# Updating React state in window.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-hooks, use-effect

I have the following problem: I want to update a state when a scroll is happening.

I used the following solution:

```js
React.useEffect(() => { window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEvent) }, [])
```

My state is:

```js
const [scrollAmount, setScrollAmount] = React.useState(0);
```

The event handler for my scroll event:

```
const scrollEvent = () => setScrollAmount(scrollAmount + 1);
```

The problem is my state doesn't update. It's quite understandable because I'm calling it just once without a re-render on the useEffect, but if I remove the `[]` of my useEffect, it will make it add even more scroll events, and I want just 1 scroll event that can update a state on `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use functional updates if you want the new state to be computed using the previous state. You can pass a function to `setScrollAmount` that will receive the previous value and return an updated value.

Check the example below:

```js
function App() {
  const [scrollAmount, setScrollAmount] = React.useState(0);
  const scrollEvent = () => setScrollAmount((prevAmount) => prevAmount + 1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollEvent);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollEvent);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Scrolls: {scrollAmount}</p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
body,
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

p:first-child {
  background-color: #fef9fa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

p:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Be careful though, scroll event will fire way too many times, so you will need to [debounce](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) it:

```js
function App() {
  const [scrollAmount, setScrollAmount] = React.useState(0);
  const debouncedScrollEvent = _.debounce(() => setScrollAmount((prevAmount) => prevAmount + 1), 250);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", debouncedScrollEvent);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", debouncedScrollEvent);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Scrolls: {scrollAmount}</p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
body,
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

p:first-child {
  background-color: #fef9fa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

p:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

p:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If for any of you want an alternative, I should ask you to try to use useRef and useImperativeHandler.

I used this:

```
scrollAmount = React.useRef(0)
```

and,

```
useImperativeHandle(scrollAmount, () => ({amount: 0, add() : { this.amount += 1 }), [])
```

and, inside the Scroll Event:

```
scrollAmount.current.add();
```

and to recieve the value:

```
scrollAmount.current.amount;
```